# Is any closed ball compact in the Weak$^*$ topology $\sigma(E^*,E)$ for a Banach Space $E$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, weak-convergence

For a Banach Space $E$, the Banach Alaoglu Bourbaki theorem asserts that the closed unit ball in $E^*$: $$B_{E^*}= \{f \in E^* \ | \  ||f|| \leq 1 \} $$

is compact in the weak$^*$ topology $\sigma(E^*,E)$.  I have already seen the proof of the theorem.  What about the ball that is not unitary?

The paper I am reading is using the fact that **every** closed ball (Of any radius) is compact, but it is never explicitly shown.  Is this trivial corolary of the Banach-Alaoglu-Bourbaki theorem? Do I have to use the definition of open coverings to show it? This would be trivial if we were talking about the usual metric topology given by the norm, but dealing with the weak$^*$ topology is not that clear.

Comment: On PDE by Brezis there is the proof, page 66, and use Tychonoff theorem.

Comment: @JohnMartin Question edited, I am talking about any closed ball, How do I translate the compactness to every closed ball of any radius?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f_0\in X^*$, $\lambda>0$, and you define $T:X^*\to X^*$ by $$Tf=f_0+\lambda f$$then $T$ is continuous in the weak* topology.

Comment: One more question, What is the simplest way to show that this aplication is continuous? Because it is not linear, so we cannot use the fact that it is bounded.

Comment: @D1X $(X^*,w^*)$ is a topological vector space. That means that the vector-space operations are continuous.